# .htaccess control to my links

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have links to my website like:

http://codecordia.com/codeframe/view/page/blog?post=name-of-the-article
or
http://codecordia.com/codeframe/view/page/product?post=name-of-the-product

I want to change to:

http://codecordia.com/blog/name-of-the-article
or
http://codecordia.com/product/name-of-the-product

I currently have made a .htaccess file like this, but I can't shorten the URL.

```
--------htaccess-------------

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

--------htaccess-------------
```

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? Usually, writing rewrite rules does not affect the way your application generates routes

Comment: Which blog engine are you using? WordPress has this feature already in the admin. I

Answer (score 0):

For your blog URL, you can use the following rule to convert your clean url to a .php file with a query string:

```
# URL
# INPUT http://codecordia.com/blog/name-of-the-article
# OUTPUT http://codecordia.com/codeframe/view/page/blog?post=name-of-the-article

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog\/(.*?) /codeframe/view/page/blog?post=$1 [L]
```

View on [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=2e45231b-1324-51a6-8de5-574264385db2)

You should be able to create the second rule easily with this example.